# Span tag not working

Tags: html

I have a horizontal menu demo below using HTML and CSS. As you can see I have put a right border on the li tag to separate the menu options. However I don't wish to have a border on the last menu option so I have used a span style to try and stop it showing. However it does not appear to be working for me. Can anyone help?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">

#menu a {
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
font-weight:bold;
}

#menu ul {
display:inline;
list-style:none;
padding:0px;
}

#menu li {
display:inline;
margin:0px;
border-right: solid black thin;
padding-right:5px;
color:black;
}



</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Prices</a></li>
    <span style="border-right:none"><li><a href="/">Contact Me</a></li></span>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Two problems:

A) You can't wrap a `li` inside a `span`, because lists (`ol`) can't contain anything else than `li`. (First thing to learn here is to allways *validate* your HTML code: http://validator.w3.org/)

B) The border is on the `li`, you are tying to remove the border from the `span`. You need to remove the border from the `li` itself, for example like this:

```
<li style="border-right:none"><a href="/">Contact Me</a></li>
```

However it's even easier if you directly define in the stylesheet that the last element shouldn't have a border:

```
#menu li:last-child {
   border-right: none;
}
```

That way you don't need to worry yourself which `li` is the last one, even if you ever decide reorder the items or add new ones to the end.

Comment: Worked a charm. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the li, not the span. Try this :

```
<span><li style="border-right:none"><a href="/">Contact Me</a></li></span>
```

Comment: You need to lose the `span` or the HTML is invalid.

Comment: Yes, but it was not the purpose of the question

Comment: But the poster could think it's ok to add a span there (or that it's even needed), although it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a li tag inside the span!
Just remove the li tag inside the span too and it will work. Eg here: http://jsfiddle.net/8cUmx/

Answer (score 0):

remove span tag and add this css

```
#menu li:last-child {
 border-right:none;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `:last-child`?